# Lowercase letters in javascript html object

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I would like to dynamically raise or lower individual letters in my label. Currently, I am supersetting the text for the elements:
`let element = document.getElementById('xxx') element.textContent = 'Label'`

I tried using `<sup>2</sup>` oder `<sub>`.
Unfortunately this has no effect. Anyone have an idea how I can get this solved?

Comment: Can you show what your expected result is?

Comment: _"Unfortunately this has no effect"_ - please don't just state stuff like this, without giving us anything to _verify_. Provide a proper [mre] of your issue, when you are asking a question like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are in Angular, so we define variables in .ts and use this variables in the .html

```
text="Label"
letterClass:boolean[]=[];

    <span *ngFor="let letter of text.split('');let i=index" 
          [class.upper]="letterClass[i]">
       {{letter}}
    </span>
```

Then you can use in .ts

```
  this.letterClass[2]=true
```

Or in .html

```
<button (click)="letterClass[2]=!letterClass[2]">click</button>
```

And your letter in position 3 have the class "upper"

e.g. this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aqm6fr?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You could create two css classes, one to superscript and one to subscript a letter, like shown [here](https://gist.github.com/unruthless/413930).
Make sure to put the letters you want to change individually into separate elements that you can address individualy like:

```html
<span id="letter1">L</span>
<span id="letter2">a</span>
<span id="letter3">b</span>
<span id="letter4">e</span>
<span id="letter5">l</span>
```

Then you can toggle the classes for the letters you want with: `document.getElementById("letter1").classList.toggle("sub")` or `document.getElementById("letter1").classList.toggle("sup")`.

(Make sure to use your correct class names and ids)

Comment: not use simple JavaScript, you're working in Angular, use binding